# На форуме, кажется, неправильно написано...

Tags: орфография

[image: ddd]

По мне, в данном случае правильно было бы написать "HTML-тэги", ибо здесь идёт присоединение иноязычного элемента к русскому самостоятельному слово, как и в случае со словами **IT-индустрия**, **3G-cоединение**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, но объяснение немного другое: неизменяемое приложение перед склоняемым главным словом пишется через дефис.

LED-дисплей

я-концепция

веб-сайт

Answer (score 2):

[image]

При посещении приложения **Steam** нашёл вот такой вот блок. :)

Answer (score 0):

**HTML-тэги**, конечнно.
Объяснение можете выбрать любое - все годится.

Инструкции даже для филологических ресурсов редко пишут грамотные люди.)))

Comment: Очень смешно, действительно. =)